# Angular Validation and an autopopulated field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have a form that has 2 drop down boxes.  A certain combination of selections causes a text box on the same page to be a required entry.  This is being done by angular.

Mind you, I have very little knowledge of Angular, but this is what I see, around the two drop down boxes.

```
"tier1Tier2_dd": [{
    "tier1_id": 42,
    "tier1_name": "Option 1",
    "tier2_id": 353,
    "tier2_name": "Option 2",
    "enforceFoo": true,
```

the enforceFoo is my issue.

the **"foo"** text box is getting data set by a jquery call
`('#foo).val('12345');`

so there is the value 12345 in the text box, but I am still getting the validation error that Foo must have a value.

If i click in the text box and hit the space bar, it goes away, so I tried simulating a `keypress` event to the text box, but that did not work.

Any other ideas how to get the page to realize that there is data in the box?

To explain it another way, my page loads, I then select the 2 options from the drop down box that give me the **"foo must have a value"** warning.  I then, in the console window, execute:
`$('#foo').val('123245')`

That puts the value into the text box, but I still have the warning and am not able to submit the form.  I need to make angular's validation realize there is a value in there.

Is there any more information I can provide to help?

TIA

Comment: thats is because your change has not been dictated  by angularJs. instead of using jQuery, append value straight to ng-model of foo text-box

Comment: You will have to change model or you have to manually trigger validation!

Comment: OK, conceptually, and theoretically, that makes sense to me. I understand that Angular makes use of the MVC pattern.  Having never used Angular, I am not sure HOW to do what you are saying.  I will look around more along this line, but some further clarification would be helpful.  Thank you

Comment: Ok.  That pointed me in the correct direction.  I am using IE, so changing my $('#foo).val('12345') to $('#foo).val('12345').change()  solved my problem; angular's model now sees the change.